# SQL Like clause in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to migrate a SQL Server stored procedure to LINQ and I am having difficulties when I have a list of partial matches that I need to find in the main table.

In short I need to replicate the following SQL into a LINQ. Any help would be much appreciated.

SQL

```
DECLARE @filters TABLE([filter] NVARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @filters VALUES ('Den%');
INSERT INTO @filters VALUES ('%zil');
INSERT INTO @filters VALUES ('%la%');

SELECT c.*  
FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Customers] c
INNER JOIN @filters f ON c.Country LIKE (f.filter)
ORDER BY Country
```

C#

```
var filters = new string[] { "Den*", "*zil", "*la*" };

var results = from C in ctx.Customers
              join f in filters c.Country like f
              Select new 
                     {
                         c.CustomerId,
                         c.Country
                     };
```

Comment: I assume you  realize that a row where country = 'Denlazil" would return 3 rows?

Answer (score 0):

Yo could use the following example:

```
var result = context.Customers.AsNoTracking()
                    .Include(x => x.Country)
                    .Where(x => x.Country.Contains("Den"));
```

as this example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = context.Customers.AsNoTracking()
                    .Include(x => x.Country)
                    .Where(x => x.Country.Contains("la") || x.Country.Startwith("Den") || x.Country.EndWith("zil"))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **EF.Functions.Like()** method provided in EF Core.
We use `%` for **LIKE** in strings and not `*`.
So your query would look like:

```
var filters = new string[] { "Den%", "%zil", "%la%" };

var result = context.Customers.AsNoTracking()
                 .Where(c => filters.Any(f => EF.Functions.Like(c.Country, f)))
                 .OrderBy(c => c.Country)
                 .ToList();
```

If you just have one filter then your query would simplify to:-

```
var filter = "%la%";

var result = context.Customers.AsNoTracking()
                 .Where(c => EF.Functions.Like(c.Country, filter))
                 .OrderBy(c => c.Country)
                 .ToList();
```